# PHP wrap two render arrays in separate divs

Tags: php, foreach

I need to wrap both my arrays in their own wrapping div outside of the foreach loop.

```
function foo() {
 //my foreach loops

 $top_content[] = $top;
 $bottom_content[] = $bottom;

 return array($top_content, $bottom_content);
}
```

Ideally I would be able to:

```
function foo() {
 //my foreach loops

 $top_content[] = '<div class="wrapper-one">' . $top . '</div>';
 $bottom_content[] = '<div class="wrapper-two">' . $bottom  . '</div>';

 return array($top_content, $bottom_content);
}
```

but then I get an error of: Notice: Array to string conversion

any help appreciated.

Comment: what is $top and $bottom? and where you are getting this notice of Array to string conversion?

Comment: Could you also show us how you are trying to use the return of `foo()`. If you try to use the `foo()` in concatenation with some string then you will again end up with `Array to string conversion` error.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
 //my foreach loops

 $top_content[0] = '<div class="wrapper-one">' . $top . '</div>';
 $bottom_content[0] = '<div class="wrapper-two">' . $bottom  . '</div>';

 return array($top_content, $bottom_content);
}
```

Comment: $top_content[] is identical to $top_content[0]. 0 index is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is so because you are trying to concatenate array with string. Since `$top` and `$bottom` could have been initialized as array before.

```
$top_content[0] = '<div class="wrapper-one">' . $top . '</div>';
$bottom_content[] = '<div class="wrapper-two">' . $bottom  . '</div>';
```

So my guess is you must be doing creating `$top` and `$bottom` as array and trying to concatenate at the end of for-each loop.

You can still do it like this.

```
$topContents    = implode('', $top);
$bottomContents = implode('', $bottom);

$top_content[0] = '<div class="wrapper-one">' . $topContents . '</div>';
$bottom_content[] = '<div class="wrapper-two">' . $bottom  . '</div>';
```

The trick is to use php's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to concatenate array first. After concatenation it returns string. This string can then further be concatenated with other strings.

Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: I'm still getting `Notice: Array to string conversion` but I think i need to refactor some things.